# Uniform continuity on discs

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis

Suppose we have a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Assume that $f$ is uniformly continuous on every interval $(-n,n), n\in \mathbb{N}$. Does that imply that f is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$? I guess the same can be asked for a function defined on any metric space $X=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B(x_o,n)$, where $x_o$ is arbitrary, assuming uniform continuity on every ball $B(x_o,n), n\in \mathbb{N}$.

EDIT: I tried to simplify the question and it became trivial. The actual question was about a holomorphic function $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, where $\Omega$ is a domain. Is it true that uniform continuity on every $D_n=\left \{ z\in \Omega:|z|<n \right \}=D(0,n) \cap \Omega, n\in \mathbb{N}$, guarantees uniform continuity in $\Omega$? If not, does the assumption that the derivatives $f^{(a)},f^{(b)}, a< b$, extend continuously on $\overline{\Omega }$, imply that every $f^{(k)},a\leqslant k\leqslant b$, extends continuously on $\overline{\Omega }$? I tried to show the last one by checking if $f^{(k)}$ is uniformly continuous on $\overline{\Omega }$, hence the question at the start, i am trying to find the minimal requirements here.

Comment: Because you're asking about continuity (or holomorphicity) on arbitrarily large disks centered at $0$, "uniformly" is a red herring: Every disk centered at $0$ has closure contained in a larger open disk, as Martin says. As for your last edit, existence of $f^{(b)}$ up to the boundary certainly implies existence of $f^{(k)}$ up to the boundary for $k \leq b$. At this stage, perhaps asking a new question is best, taking care to state exactly the hypotheses you mean?

Comment: The result for discs fails. Just use $z^2$ on $\Omega = \mathbb C.$

Comment: Yes, it does fail for $f(z)=z^2$. Though for $a=1$ and $b=2$, if i take $k$ between them, namely $k=1$ or $k=2$, then $f^{(k)}(z)=2z$ or $f^{(k)}=2$ and in both of these cases $f^{(k)}$ is uniformly continuous on $\Omega=\mathbb{C}$. That's what i really want.

Answer (score 3):

Your $f $ is automatically uniformly continuous on any interval, $[a,b] $ (in any compact set, actually). But  it will often fail to be uniformly  continuous on the whole line; typical example is $f (x)=x^2$,

Comment: Sorry, i meant open intervals. The answer is trivial using closed intervals.

Comment: The answer is also trivial using open intervals, because every closed interval is inside an open interval and viceversa. Same function.

Comment: It seems it has no use in R. I edited again.